# How to use grep to search ALL folders for text?

Tags: grep

I'm having issues with searching through ALL the directories at once with `grep`. When I use the command:

```
find . -name "*.txt" | xargs grep texthere
```

It just takes forever and then gives me "no such file or directory" errors.

Why is this happening and is there nothing easier than `grep`? Or am I using the wrong command?

Answer (score 1):

If you have GNU grep, the grep itself supports "-r" option to search recursively, as suggested by @Ouroborus.

If unfortunately your grep does not support such option, like in SunOS, you can use following commands instead:

```
find . -name "*.txt" -exec grep -n your_pattern {} /dev/null \;
```

The tricky is `/dev/null` added to ensure each execution of grep has two files (the file matched *.txt and the /dev/null) provided, forcing it print the name of files being searched. And you can add `-type f` option of `find` to refine the scope of `find`.

Comment: Wouldn't this be *slower* since it invokes `grep` once for each file?

Answer (score 0):

As in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16957078/367865), you're probably better off with:

> `grep -rnw '/path/to/somewhere/' -e "pattern"`
>
> - `-r` or `-R` is recursive,
> - `-n` is line number, and
> - `-w` stands match the whole word.
> - `-l` (lower-case L) can be added to just give the file name of matching files.

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting errors about permissions (you don't say you do), then I'm guessing you're standing in either the root directory (`/`) or in some path where you don't have permission to read all files, such as in `/etc` or in `/var`.  But since you say it takes an awfully long time, I'm leaning more towards the first assumption (the root directory).

If you want to search absolutely *all* files on the *whole* system, than what you're doing is pretty much right.  It *will* take a long time no matter what you do. It's just an awful lot of files to search.

You can use `find` to narrow down the amount of files to look at.

At the moment, you have

```
$ find . -name "*.txt" | xargs grep texthere
```

Since it looks like you're only interested in plain text files, we can exclude any other type of file (executables):

```
$ find / -type f \! -perm -o=x -name "*.txt" | xargs grep texthere
```

I replaced `.` with `/` here, because that's where I *think* you are (correct me if I'm wrong). I'm also specifying that I want *files* (`-type f`) that are *not executable* (`\! -perm -o=x`) (the `!` needs to be escaped so that your shell doesn't do funny things with it).

Now, there's a couple of more things we can do. One is a safety thing, and the other may *possibly* improve speed a tiny bit.

Some file names might have spaces in them, or other wonky character that we usually don't want in file names.  To be able to pass these properly between `find` and `grep` we do

```
$ find / -type f \! -perm -o=x -name "*.txt" -print0 | xargs -0 grep texthere
```

This (`-print0`) means each file name will be delimited by a `nul` character (`\0`) rather than a space character. And the corresponding option to `xargs` for receiving these as `nul`-delimited file names is `-0`.

It's because you're not using those two option that I believe you get those "no such file or directory" errors.

The speed thing is `fgrep`.  This is a utility which is exactly equivalent to `grep -F` that you should use if your search string is a plain text string with no regular expressions in it.

So, if you have a plain text string and you want to look for it in every single file on the whole system:

```
$ find / -type f \! -perm -o=x -name "*.txt" -print0 | xargs -0 fgrep texthere
```

The permission thing... Obviously there will be files that you aren't able to read.  You can either run `find` and `fgrep` with `sudo` prepended to them:

```
$ sudo find ... | xargs -0 sudo fgrep texthere
```

Or you could try to craft another `-perm` flag for `find` (and also get it to ignore directories that you can't enter), but that would be too time consuming and result in a ridiculously long command line, so I won't do that here.

Or you could just `sudo -s` to get a root shell and run the thing from there... but I would generally advise against that because people have a tendency to mess up their systems by forgetting they are `root`.

**ANOTHER SOLUTION** would be to use the `locate` command to locate all the `.txt` files on the whole system.  The `locate` command doesn't search the file hierarchy but instead uses a database (which is usually updated daily, so not *all* files may be there). The database does only contain files in directories accessible by all users, so if you have removed the read-permissions on your own directories, your files won't be there.

So, replacing the `find` command above with the `locate` almost-equivalent:

```
$ locate '*.txt' -0 | xargs -0 fgrep texthere
```

The `-0` option (or `--null` on some systems) corresponds to the `--print0` option of `find`.